# Mount password protected Samba share with Kerberos ticket

Tags: keychain, active-directory, smb, automount, kerberos

My iMac is connected to the Active Directory server, with no additional GID and UID setup, I can login to the OS X using AD user credentials, but I also need to mount the Desktops and probably other shares.

The problem is that I use Linux hosted Samba servers, and I need to push the Desktop's share path to the OS X clients somehow. I can mount that using OS X' Samba client, but I need to do that automatically. As I'm already authenticated against AD, there must be a way to use my Kerberos ticket to access the share without password, isn't it?

Some guys say that it is possible with passwords stored in keychain, but I don't get it much, when are passwords stored in keychain?  Should I add it once, and will that work forever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the *dsconfigad* tool - to enable single sign-on we need to fire the `dsconfigad -enableSSO` command, after that there is no need to retype the passwords, Kerberos tickets are being reused.

To mount a Samba share subfolder automatically, you need to enable "Show connected servers" in the Finder preferences, then use <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> to connect to the subfolder in Samba share, and create an alias on Desktop or wherever you want, after you can disable showing connected servers on Desktop. Then you can just click on the alias and it will open the shared subfolder.